# How do I add an array of data points to a Highchart series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a requirement where I get chunks of data asynchronously. When i get the first chunk, I create a new series but for all other chunks. I want to add the chunk of data to the existing series. I can see in Highcharts documentation, there is addpoint method, but it adds each point and this would take a long time. Is there a way to add a chunk of data to the series in one go. In my case each chunk of data is an array of 2500 data points.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the ajax callback just get the existing serial data, append whatever data you need to the series, and re-set the series data.

```
callback: 
function(msg) {
    var oldData = myChart.get('mySeriesName').data;
    var newData = formatMsgForHighCharts(msg);
    var combinedData= oldData.concat(newData);
    myChart.get('mySeriesName').setData(combinedData);
}
```

The line:

```
 var newData = formatMsgForHighCharts(msg);
```

doesn't need to be there if the message is already formatted properly, just pass msg.d into the concat function.